# How to strip EXIF except "date taken" using Imagemagick?

Tags: image-processing, imagemagick, image-manipulation

I want to reduce image size by stripping EXIF metadata (`convert -strip ...`), but the problem is I want to preserve the "date taken" entry. Is it possible? For example: `convert -quality 80 -strip-except "date taken" source.jpg dest.jpg`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It depends how important it is to save the "date taken" *"in the correct place"* where it can be parsed by normal image viewing programs. If you just want the original date/time in the file **somewhere/anywhere**, you can extract it and save it in the "Comment" field like this:

```
# Use ImageMagick to get the exif:DateTime, e.g. "exif:DateTime: 2014:12:23 13:51:00"
d=$(identify -verbose image.jpg | grep "exif:DateTime:")

# Strip EXIF but then put DateTime in the "Comment" field
convert image.jpg -strip -set comment "$d" result.jpg
```

**Update**

Actually, you can get the date/time more succinctly, and in a platform-independent way than above by using:

```
identify -format "%[EXIF:DateTime]" image.jpg
2014:12:23 13:51:00
```

The date and time are now in the "Comment" field, it's just that ImageViewers won't find it there - although you can with:

```
identify -verbose result.jpg
Image: result.jpg
  Format: JPEG (Joint Photographic Experts Group JFIF format)
  Mime type: image/jpeg
  Class: DirectClass
  Geometry: 3264x2448+0+0
  Resolution: 72x72
  Print size: 45.3333x34
  Units: PixelsPerInch
  Type: TrueColor
  Endianess: Undefined
  Colorspace: sRGB
  Depth: 8-bit
  Channel depth:
    red: 8-bit
  ...
  ...
  Interlace: None
  Intensity: Undefined
  Compose: Over
  Page geometry: 3264x2448+0+0
  Dispose: Undefined
  Iterations: 0
  Compression: JPEG
  Quality: 96
  Orientation: Undefined
  Properties:
    comment:     exif:DateTime: 2014:12:23 13:51:00
```

A better way to do it though is using `jhead`. It has these options:

```
-ft        Set filetime to EXIF time
-purejpg   Strip EXIF, IPTC and other meta-data
-mkexif    Create a minimal EXIF section
-dsft      Set EXIF time to filetime
```

which you can string together as you wish, but probably in the order I have shown.